# C#. How to return char?

Tags: c#, string, function, search, character

I need to write a function that returns all characters that occur 2 or more times in the text. There isn't any problem when I use it without function (for example on button click). That's how I do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alph.Length; i++) // alph is my text(string)
        {
            int count = allText.Split(alphCh[i]).Length - 1; 
            if (count >= 2)                   
                listView2.Items.Add(alphCh[i].ToString());                
        }
```

That's how I write function:

```
public char[] chars2(string text)
    {
        char[] allChar = text.ToCharArray();
        string allText = text.ToString();
        string allTextL = text.ToLower();
        string alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char[] alphCh = alph.ToCharArray();  
        char[] result = new char[0];
        int allcount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < alph.Length; i++)
        {
            int count = allText.Split(alphCh[i]).Length - 1;
            if (count >= 2)
            {
                allcount++;
                result = new char[allcount];
                for (int j = 0; j < allcount; j++)
                {
                    result[j] = alphCh[i];
                    return result;
                }
            }               
        }  
        return result;            
    }
```

But function returns just first character that occurs 2 or more times in the text. For example I write abcbca - func returns a, and I want to func returns a, b, c, to write it into ListView for example. What do I do wrong? Please, I need your help so much. Thanx.

Comment: The return in the loop stops the loop.

Comment: No, it might occur 2 or more times anywhere in the text: abcdabcd, also returns a, b, c, d.

Comment: Yochai Timmer, thanx, but what to do? I've tried to write continue but it's not usefull.

Comment: Mark Byers, please reread my question, I've modified it. When I write abdcbda, function might return a, b, d.

Comment: @Daria: Thanks, that makes it much clearer.

Comment: @Daria: What version of C# / .NET are you using?

Comment: Do you only want duplicate letters, and ignore digits, whitespace, etc. ?

Comment: Oh, some comments was hidden, i didn't see it. Elian Ebbing, yes. I just want to fint duplicated English alphabet characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have C# 3.0 or newer you can use LINQ:

```
char[] result = text
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanx a lot lot lot! It works! But one question: can I search just latin character (just characters of English alphabet)? Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Linq can simplify. Does this meet the requirements?

```
"aabbccpoiu".ToCharArray()
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
```

It returns a, b and c.

Comment: You don't actually need to call `ToCharArray`. The class `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, despite Intellisense showing that that the class `string` doesn't have a GroupBy extension method (it does).

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was news for me. Fun how the rest of the code was identical.

Answer (score 1):

Return a List instead, and use it inside the funciton as you do with the listview; just use `List<char> rVal = new List<char>();` and then `rVal.Add(character)` if its not already added

**Also remove the return inside the loop:**

Comment: Thanx, I removed. I had this thought but is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion=

```
public List<char> getMoreThanTwice(string text) {

char[] characters = text.toCharArray();
Dictionary<char, int> chars = new Dictionary<char, int>();
List<char> morethantwice = new List<char>();

for (int i=0;i<characters.Length;i++) {
  if (chars.containsKey(characters[i])) {
   chars[characters[i]] = chars[characters[i]] + 1;
  }else{
   chars.Add(characters[i], 1);
   }
}

foreach (KeyValuePair keypair in chars) {
   if (keypair.Value >= 2)  {
     morethantwice.Add(keypair.Key);
   }
 }

return morethantwice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `return result;` will return directly when it has found the first result.

Comment: Thanx, and what do does it mean?